# Is conditional rendering in next.js to wait for firebase to check user existence bad for SSG or in general?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, next.js

I created a state variable called 'loading' to check whether firebase finished checking for the existence of a user or not. And if it is still loading, I render null. If it stops loading, I render the children (which will handle redirecting to login if no user was found).

However, what I am afraid of is that this could be bad for NextJS SSG support.

Is this fine or like I said it's bad? If yes, is there a better solution?

```
return (
  <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user, signup, signin, logout }}>
    {loading ? null : children}
  </AuthContext.Provider>
);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "bad for SSG"? Is the authentication flow done on the client-side?

Comment: Yes it is done with firebase on the client side using AuthContext